# How to do preg_replace that only matches particular conditions?

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling to write a preg_replace command that achieves what I need.

Essentially I have the following array (all the items follow one of these four patterns):

```
$array = array('Dogs/Cats', 'Dogs/Cats/Mice', 'ANIMALS/SPECIES Dogs/Cats/Mice', '(Animals/Species) Dogs/Cats/Mice' );
```

I need to be able to get the following result:

```
Dogs/Cats = Dogs or Cats

Dogs/Cats/Mice = Dogs or Cats or Mice

ANIMALS/SPECIES Dogs/Cats/Mice = ANIMALS/SPECIES Dogs or Cats or Mice

(Animals/Species) Dogs/Cats/Mice = (Animals/Species) Dogs or Cats or Mice
```

So basically replace slashes in anything that isn't capital letters or brackets.

I am starting to grasp it but still need some guidance:

```
preg_replace('/(\(.*\)|[A-Z]\W[A-Z])[\W\s\/]/', '$1 or', $array);
```

As you can see this recognises the first patterns but I don't know where to go from there

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `\G` anchors to assert the position at the previous match and use `\K` to forget what was matched to match only a `/`.

You could optionally match `ANIMALS/SPECIES` or `(Animals/Species)` at the start.

```
(?:^(?:\(\w+/\w+\)\h+|[A-Z]+/[A-Z]+\h+)?|\G(?!^))\w+\K/
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^` Assert start of string
  - `(?:` Non capturing group, match either

    - `\(\w+/\w+\)\h+` Match between `(....)` 1+ word chars with a `/` between ending with 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
    - `|` Or
    - `[A-Z]+/[A-Z]+\h+` Match 1+ times [A-Z], `/` and again 1+ times `[A-Z]`
  - `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the previous match
- `)\w+` Close non capturing group and match 1+ times a word char
- `\K/` Forget what was matched, and match a `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z2TqAD/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/fkXnA)

In the replacement use a space, `or` and a space

For example

```
$array = array('Dogs/Cats', 'Dogs/Cats/Mice', 'ANIMALS/SPECIES Dogs/Cats/Mice', '(Animals/Species) Dogs/Cats/Mice');
$re = '~(?:^(?:\(\w+/\w+\)\h+|[A-Z]+/[A-Z]+\h+)?|\G(?!^))\w+\K/~';
$array = preg_replace($re, " or ", $array);
print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dogs or Cats
    [1] => Dogs or Cats or Mice
    [2] => ANIMALS/SPECIES Dogs or Cats or Mice
    [3] => (Animals/Species) Dogs or Cats or Mice
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this exactly clears up my confusions! I appreciate the extensive answer, and since I couldn't find any similar cases, it should help a lot of others too!

Comment: how might this also be expanded to make `ANIMALS/SPECIES Dogs and Cats/Mice` to `ANIMALS/SPECIES Dogs and Cats or Mice`? I would've thought that final slash would always be applicable throughout the remainder of the string?

Comment: @JamesCartwright The `\G` asserts the position at the previous match and `\w+` will not match the space between.  So you might make it a bit of a broader match matching not a forward slash using a negated character class  `[^/]+` instead of `\w` See https://regex101.com/r/1xcdap/1/. Or you add a space to the character class `[ \w]+` See https://regex101.com/r/1xcdap/2. You can make it as specific as you want. If there can be only repeating spaces and word characters you could use `\w+(?: \w+)` See https://regex101.com/r/1xcdap/3

Comment: Perfect! Learned more here than anywhere else :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you present your problem with your example strings, doing:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?:\S+ )?[^/]*+\K.~', ' or ', $array);
```

looks enough. In other words, you only have to check if there's a space somewhere to consume the beginning of the string until it and to discard it from the match result using `\K`.

But to avoid future disappointments, it is sometimes useful to put yourself in the shoes of the Devil to consider more complex cases and ask embarrassing questions:

What if a category, a subcategory or an item contains a space?

```
~
(?:^
    (?:
        \( [^)]* \)
      |
        \p{Lu}+ (?> [ ] \p{Lu}+ \b )* 
        (?> / \p{Lu}+ (?> [ ] \p{Lu}+ \b )* )* 
    ) 
    [ ]
)?

[^/]*+ \K .
~xu
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQR5Dv/1)

In the same way, to deal with hyphens, single quotes or whatever, you can replace `[ ]` with `[^\pL/]` (a class that excludes letters and the slash) or something more specific.